# XmlConfiguratorAttribute not working with this.Log and log4net?

Tags: log4net

I'm using this.Log and am trying to get the application to start using the following attribute:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

This doesn't seem to work though and when I turn on log4net debugging I can't seem to find out why.  I looked at the this.Log code though and found the following line in the Log4NetLog.cs file:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Could this be overriding my own assembly settings?  Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: At the time of your question, were you aware of XmlConfiguratorAttribute limitations? This attribute may not be taken into account if first use of LoggerManager does not occurs in the assembly containing the attribute. For this reason, I highly favor the alternate solution proposed by sgmoore. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.html

Comment: Really? That is very useful information to have.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the source you could remove the line and recompile.

Alternatively, you can override the settings at runtime, eg add the line (either to the start of your program or in a static constructor)

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("Log4net.config"));
```